# Error due to private access

Tags: java

So i'm attempting to write a code that uses Point and Line in class. It's intended function is to create a line with two points, then find the slope of the line. This is what the code looks like

```
public class LineMain{
   public static void main (String[]args){
   Point p1=new Point(22,3);
   Point p2=new Point(4,7);
   Line Line1=new Line(p1,p2);
   System.out.println(Line1.getSlope());
   }
}
```

---

```
public class Line{
   private Point p1;
   private Point p2;

   public Line(Point p1, Point p2){
      this.p1=p1;
      this.p2=p2;
   }

   public Point getP1(){
      return p1;
   }

   public Point getP2(){
      return p2;
   }    
   public double getSlope(){
        int slope;
        slope = ((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x));
        return slope;
   }
}
```

---

```
public class Point{
   private int x;
   private int y;
   /*
   public Point(){
      this(0,0);
   }
   */
   public Point(){
      x=0;
      y=0;
   }

   public Point(int x, int y){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
   }

   public Point(Point p){
      x=p.x;
      y=p.y;
   }

   /*
   public Point (int x1,int y1){
      x=x1;
      y=y1;
   }   
   */
   public int getX(){
      return x;
   }

   public int getY(){
      return y;
   }

   public void setX(int x){
      this.x=x;
   }

   public void setY(int y){
      this.y=y;
   }            

   public String toString(){
      return "("+x+", "+y+")";
   }   

   public double distance(Point other){
      double x1=other.x;
      double y1=other.y;
      double z=Math.pow((x1-x),2)+Math.pow((y1-y),2);
      return z;
   }

   public double slope(Point other){
      double x1=other.x;
      double y1=other.y;
      if (x1==x){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("no");
      }else{   
         double z=(y1-y)/(x1-x);
         return z;
         }
      }
}
```

But every time I attempt to run the code it pops up with the error:

```
Line.java:24: error: y has private access in Point
        slope = ((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x));
                    ^
Line.java:24: error: y has private access in Point
        slope = ((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x));
                         ^
Line.java:24: error: x has private access in Point
        slope = ((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x));
                                ^
Line.java:24: error: x has private access in Point
        slope = ((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x));
                                     ^
4 errors
```

Please help!

Comment: And what is your question? Is the error message not clear? It means that the `Line` instance is not allowed to access the private members of the `Point` instances. Private members are not supposed to be accessed form outside the class. If you are not familiar with the visibility settings of members, I suggest to read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

Comment: It seems x & y are private members of class Point. Please upload the definition of class Point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices, although I **really** hope you choose the latter.

1. Make the fields of `Point` public.  This will allow you to use them as you currently are at the cost of violating conventions.

   ```
   public class Point {
       public double x, y; // Possible
       // constructor detail
   }
   ```
2. Create a `getX()` and `getY()` for your fields of `Point` and keep them as `private`.  You'll have to rewrite the usage of `x` and `y`, though, at the cost of preserving conventions.

   ```
   public class Point {
       private double x, y;
       // constructor detail

       public double getX() {
           return x;
       }

       public double getY() {
           return y;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add methods `getX()` and `getY()` to the `Point` class, and then use them in your `Line` class.